# How to handle IOmniParallelJoin finalization in OmniThreadLibrary?

Tags: delphi, omnithreadlibrary

I'm using `IOmniParallelJoin` to compute the several tasks in parallel with `NoWait` function because I want the GUI to stay responsive. But I also need to know when the computation is finished. Is there any event which is triggered in such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `OnStop` function to inject some code or use a Task Configuration via `TaskConfig` and assign the code via `OnTerminated`. The difference is that `OnStop` is called inside one of the worker threads while `OnTerminated` is called inside the main thread.

Comment: One more difference which I noticed is that OnTerminated event will be called as many times as there are threads (tasks) "join" have. How to deal with the situation when it is required to run the code in the main thread only once?